# How to set responsive divs in my case?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I want to use col-md-2 for the large pc view and col-xs-12 for tablet view.

My problem is that when I turn to larger width view, I see there are gaps between each div. This doesn't happen in the tablet view.

Html code:

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-12 box1">
                    test
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-12 box2">
                    test 2
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-12 box1">
                    test
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-12 box2">
                    test 2
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-12 box1">
                    test
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-12 box2">
                    test 2
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-12 box1">
                    test
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-12 box2">
                    test 2
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-12">
                    test
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-12 test2">
                    test 2
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/0qarh5yt/2/)

Can anyone help me about it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to nest the grid. If you nest the grid you need an additional `<div class="row">` between the two column classes to offset the padding.

For example the `<div>` with the class `col-xs-12 col-md-2` has a direct child `<div>` with class `col-xs-3 col-md-12 box1`.

Change this from

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-12 box1">
```

into

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-12 box1">
```

I've updated your example to add these `<div class="row">`'s

```css
.box1 {
  background-color: grey;
}
.box2 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-1"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-12 box1">
            test
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-12 box2">
            test 2
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-12 box1">
            test
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-12 box2">
            test 2
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-12 box1">
            test
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-12 box2">
            test 2
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-12 box1">
            test
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-12 box2">
            test 2
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-12">
            test
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-12 test2">
            test 2
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes but then in the tablet view, there is no padding on the left of grey column and right of the red box anymore. Please see my jsfiddle link, I have paddings in tablet view +1 though

Comment: You could double the padding on the `.container` by setting it to `padding-left: 30px` and `padding-right: 30px` or rethink why you need nesting.

Answer (score 0):

The gaps are defined in Bootstrap grid settings. Classes with xs-* are all 100% width blocks, so there are no gaps.
If you want to have grid system without gaps on all screen sizes, you need to customize your Bootstrap build - http://getbootstrap.com/customize/