# How to show padding of the elements in my case?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I asked a responsive question in my previous post.

[How to set responsive divs in my case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27321380/how-to-set-responsive-divs-in-my-case)

I fixed my html to be valid html codes but it seems like I don't have the padding on the left of red column and right of the gray column anymore in tablet view. I think I do have valid bootstrap class but I am not sure what happen. Can someone help me out about this?

My jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/0qarh5yt/6/

```
<div class="container">
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
             <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-12 box1">
                    test
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-12 box2">
                    test 2
                 </div>
             </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
             <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-12 box1">
                        test
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-12 box2">
                    test 2
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
             <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-12 box1">
                    test
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-12 box2">
                    test 2
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
             <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-12 box1">
                    test
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-12 box2">
                    test 2
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
             <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-12 box1">
                    test
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-12 box2">
                    test 2
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If this is just a refinement to your previous question you linked to, you should update your question there instead of asking a new one.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Using padding is the incorrect way to fix this problem. You should adjust your xs-x values, else it reduces the usefulness of the responsive grid. Note that the grid system in Bootstrap each row holds 12 col's.

Comment: is it: http://jsfiddle.net/banzay52/qs3ph1oq/1/ - what you want?

Answer (score -1):

You have negative margins on row:

```
.row {
margin-right: -15px;
margin-left: -15px;
}
```

if you delete these or set them to 0 it will solve your issue
(everything else is ok);

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maio/0qarh5yt/10/)**